# Removing empty option in Drop Down Box in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am a beginner in google appscript. I have a dropdown box in my web app after logging in into the web app but I don't know why it is showing an extra empty box in the dropdown box. I have attached some pictures and my coding to explain myself better. Hope you guys can lend me a hand. Thank you.

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bM8l6JefFsPrlJnTWf56wOhnuSjdIwg3hMbY1tN1Zp8/edit#gid=1775459006";
var streetSheetName = "JALAN SANGGUL 4";

function doGet(e) {
  var streetSheetName = "JALAN SANGGUL 4"; // Added
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("streetSheetName", streetSheetName); // Added
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('WebAppLogin');
}

function checkLogin(username, password) {
  var found_record = '';
  var name = '';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet = ss.getSheetByName("USERNAMES");
  var getLastRow =  webAppSheet.getLastRow();
  
  for(var i = 2; i <= getLastRow; i++) {
   if(webAppSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue().toUpperCase() == username.toUpperCase() && webAppSheet.getRange(i, 7).getValue() == password) {
     found_record = 'TRUE';
     name = webAppSheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue().toUpperCase() + " " + webAppSheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue().toUpperCase();
     streetSheetName = webAppSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue().toUpperCase();
   } else if (username.toUpperCase() == 'ADMIN' && password == 'ADMINPASSWORD') {
     found_record = 'TRUE';
     name = webAppSheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue().toUpperCase() + " " + webAppSheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue().toUpperCase();
     streetSheetName = webAppSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue().toUpperCase();
   }    
  }

PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("streetSheetName", streetSheetName); // Added
if(found_record == '') {
  found_record = 'FALSE'; 
}

  return [found_record, username,name];
}

function GetRecords(username,filter) {
  var filteredDataRangeValues = GetUsernameAssociatedProperties(username);
  var resultArray = GetPaymentRecords(filteredDataRangeValues,filter);
  var resultFilter = getYears();

  result = {
    data: resultArray,
    filter: resultFilter
  };
  return result;
}

function getYears() { 
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var yearSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Configuration"); 
  var getLastRow = yearSheet.getLastRow();
  var return_array = [];
  for(var i = 2; i <= getLastRow; i++)
  {
      if(return_array.indexOf(yearSheet.getRange(i, 2).getDisplayValue()) === -1) {
        return_array.push(yearSheet.getRange(i, 2).getDisplayValue());
      }
  }
  return return_array;  
}

function changePassword(username, newPassword) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName("USERNAMES");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:A").createTextFinder(username).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
  if (range) {
    range.offset(0, 6).setValue(newPassword);
  }
}

function GetUsernameAssociatedProperties(username) {
  var filteredDataRangeValues = '';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var displaySheet = ss.getSheetByName("USERNAMES");
  var dataRangeValues = displaySheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  if (username.toUpperCase() == 'ADMIN') {
    dataRangeValues.shift();
    filteredDataRangeValues = dataRangeValues;
  } else {
    filteredDataRangeValues = dataRangeValues.filter(row => row[0].toUpperCase() == username.toUpperCase());
  }
  return filteredDataRangeValues;  
}

function GetPaymentRecords(userProperties,filter) {
  var streetSheetName = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("streetSheetName"); // Added
  var transpose = m => m[0].map((_, i) => m.map(x => x[i]));
  var resultArray = [];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var displaySheet = ss.getSheetByName(streetSheetName);
  var addressValues = displaySheet.getRange("B:C").getValues();
  var paidMonthValues = displaySheet.getRange(1, 7, displaySheet.getLastRow(), displaySheet.getLastColumn() - 6).getValues();
  //Logger.log(addressValues);
  //Logger.log(transpose(paidMonthValues));
  userProperties.forEach((v, i) => {
    var userHouseNumber = v[1];
    var userStreet = v[2];
    var column = addressValues.reduce(function callbackFn(accumulator, currentValue, index, array) {
      if (currentValue[0] == userHouseNumber && currentValue[1] == userStreet) {
        return index
      } else {
        return accumulator
      }
    }, '');
    //Logger.log(column);
    Logger.log(filter)
    Logger.log(paidMonthValues);
    
    if(filter=="None"){
      var result = transpose(paidMonthValues).map(function callbackFn(element, index, array) {
        return [element[0], userHouseNumber, userStreet, element[column] || '']
      });
    }else{
      var result = transpose(paidMonthValues).map(function callbackFn(element, index, array) {
        if(element[0].includes(filter))return [element[0], userHouseNumber, userStreet, element[column] || '']
      });
    }
    
    resultArray = resultArray.concat(result);
    //Logger.log(resultArray);  
  })

  //Remove null elements
  resultArray = resultArray.filter(element=>{
    Logger.log(element!=null)
    return element != null;
  });
  return resultArray;
}
```

**WebAppLogin.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var username = ""; // Added
    function GetRecords() {
    var spin = "<span class=\"spinner-border spinner-border-sm\" role=\"status\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>";
    spin += " Loading...";
    document.getElementById("LoginButton").innerHTML = spin;

    username = document.getElementById("username").value; // Modified
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
      
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(output) {
        console.log(output);
        var username = output[1];
        var name = output[2];
        if(output[0] == 'TRUE') {
          document.getElementById("loginDisplay").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("dataDisplay").style.display = "block";  
          document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "";
          document.getElementById("currentUser").value = username;
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayTable).GetRecords(username,"None");

        } else if(output[0] == 'FALSE') {
          document.getElementById("firstLastName").innerHTML = "";
          document.getElementById("currentUser").value = "";
          document.getElementById("myFilter").innerHTML = "";
          document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Failed to Login";
          document.getElementById("LoginButton").innerHTML = "Login";   
        }
      }).checkLogin(username, password);
    }
    
    function filter(){
      var filterStr = document.getElementById("filterYear").value;
      var user = document.getElementById("currentUser").value;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayTable).GetRecords(user,filterStr);
    }

    function displayTable(result) {
      var ar = result.data;
      var filterString = result.filter;
      ar = ar.sort((a, b) => new Date(a).getTime() > new Date(b).getTime() ? -1 : 1).splice(-12); // <--- Added
      var username = document.getElementById("currentUser").value;
      if(ar.length > 0) {
        var displayTable = '<table class=\"table\" id=\"mainTable\" >';

        displayTable += "<tr>";
        displayTable += "<th>Month</th>";
        displayTable += "<th>House Number</th>";
        displayTable += "<th>Street</th>";
        displayTable += "<th>Payment Status</th>";
        displayTable += "</tr>";

        ar.forEach(function(item, index) {
          displayTable += "<tr>";
          displayTable += "<td>"+item[0]+"</td>";
          displayTable += "<td>"+item[1]+"</td>";
          displayTable += "<td>"+item[2]+"</td>";
          displayTable += "<td>"+item[3]+"</td>";
          displayTable += "</tr>";
        });

        displayTable += "</table>";

      } else {
        var displayTable = "<span style=\"font-weight: bold\" >No Records Found</span>";
      }
      
       var filter = '';
      if(filterString.length > 0) {
        filter += '<label for="years" style="font-size: 20px">Select the Year</label><br><select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="filterYear" name="years" required><option value="" selected>Choose...</option>';
        
        filterString.forEach(str => {
          filter += '<option value="'+str+'">'+str+'</option>';
        });


        filter += '</select><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="FilterButton" onclick="filter()" >Submit</button>';
      }
      
      var today = new Date();
      var year = today.getFullYear();
      var month = today.getMonth();
      if (!ar.some(([a,,,d]) => {
        var t = new Date(a);
        return year == t.getFullYear() && month == t.getMonth() && d.toUpperCase() == "PAID";
        })) {
              document.getElementById("digitalgoods-030521182921-1").style.display = "block";
            }
      document.getElementById("displayRecords").innerHTML = displayTable;
      document.getElementById("firstLastName").innerHTML = "USER: " + name;
      document.getElementById("myFilter").innerHTML = filter;
      document.getElementById("LoginButton").innerHTML = "Login";
      document.getElementById("username").value = '';
      document.getElementById("password").value = '';
    }
    
    //change the link according to ur webapp latest version
    function LogOut(){  
      window.open("https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwKa4sQ441WUIqmU40laBP0mfiqNMiN-NghEvwUnJY/dev",'_top');
    }
      
    function changePassword(){
    var result = confirm("Want to Change Password?");
    if (result) {
    var newPassword = document.getElementById("newPassword").value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => alert('Password changed')).changePassword(username, newPassword);
    }

  }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <h2> Resident Payment Status Portal</h2>

  <div id="loginDisplay" style="padding: 10px;" >

    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label>User Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" required/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label>Password</label><br>
      <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" required/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="LoginButton" onclick="GetRecords()" >
      Login      
    </button>

    <span id="errorMessage" style="color: red" ></span>

  </div>
  
  <hr>
  <div style="display:none" id="dataDisplay"  >
    <div>
      <h2 id="firstLastName"></h2>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="currentUser" value=""/>
    <div id ="myFilter" class="form-group"></div>
    <div id="displayRecords" style="padding: 10px;" ></div>

  <!----Paypal Button-------->
    <hr>
    <div id="digitalgoods-030521182921-1" style="display: none;"></div>
     <script>(function (div, currency) {var item_total = {currency_code: currency,value: '50.00',},tax_total = {currency_code: currency,value: '0.00' },render = function () {window.paypal.Buttons({createOrder: function (data, actions) {return actions.order.create({application_context: {brand_name: "",landing_page: "BILLING",shipping_preference: "NO_SHIPPING",payment_method: {payee_preferred: "UNRESTRICTED"}},purchase_units: [{description: "",soft_descriptor: "digitalgoods",amount: {breakdown: {item_total: item_total,tax_total: tax_total},value: '50.00' },items: [{name: "Monthly Fees",quantity: 1,description: "",sku: "1",unit_amount: item_total,tax: tax_total}]}]});},onApprove: function (data, actions) {return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {div.innerHTML = "Order completed. You\x27ll receive an email shortly!";});},onCancel: function (data) {},onError: function (err) {div.innerHTML = "<pre>" + err.toString()}}).render("#digitalgoods-030521182921-1");},init = function () {window.digitalgoods = window.digitalgoods || [];window.digitalgoods.push(render);var file = "https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AS-86gVX_DfakSkq6YZDJRdKZb4SMIziOd5c9DIKy4extQrpb0VFEprDleB_duKI4BJQQRewUdfliZEf\x26currency=MYR";var script = document.createElement("script");script.type = "text/javascript";script.src = file;script.onload = function() {var i = window.digitalgoods.length;while (i--) {window.digitalgoods[i]();}};div.appendChild(script);};init();})(document.getElementById("digitalgoods-030521182921-1"), "MYR");</script>
  
  <!-----Change Password----------->
  <div>
      <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" onclick="changePassword()">Change Password</button>-->
      
      <!-- Button trigger modal -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
      Change Password
      </button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Change Password</h3>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Enter New Password</label><br>
                  <input type="password" id="newPassword" class="form-control" required/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="changePassword()">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <!-----Log Out----------->
    <div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" onclick="LogOut()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Log out
      </button>
    </div>
   
  </div>
  

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think its ok to just paste your whole project and breifly say "there is a problem with x" - please narrow down the question, give us a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), tell us about your debugging efforts, give us a way to test our solutions to your issue. At least tell us what you think the problem is and what you have tried to do to solve it - see [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in your script, the dropdown list is created in the function `displayTable` of Javascript side. And, I thought that the value of `filterString` might have the empty element. In that case, how about the following modification? Please modify the function `displayTable` of Javascript side as follows.

#### From:

```
filterString.forEach(str => {
```

#### To:

```
filterString.filter(String).forEach(str => {
```

#### Reference:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Bro I did the changes as you said bro. But now it after I logging in and select the year in dropdown box if says that record is not found bro. Can you help me with it sorry. 
https://script.google.com/home/projects/1DdRKqUX__-ZITUgTZanQ_A7hUL1kcc0TZOeFmn58wYsX_o_7cqNExnYo/edit - Link to the appscript

Comment: @LEE WEI LIANG Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `But now it after I logging in and select the year in dropdown box if says that record is not found bro.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: Sorry bro for not explaining myself better. So now bro, if you compile my coding and go into the web app, you should able to log in with the username and password bro but after loggigng in if we try to see the payment history of 2020 and select it in the dropdown box, it says that records not found bro

Comment: @LEE WEI LIANG Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I had thought that your question is `Removing empty option in Drop Down Box in Google App Script`. My answer is for your this question. But from your replying, I thought that that your question might have been changed. How about this?

Comment: @LEE WEI LIANG Thank you for replying. I understood that your question is `Removing empty option in Drop Down Box in Google App Script`. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, I think that the issue of your replying is new question. Because your question is to remove the empty options from the dropdown list. So, at first, how about resolving your this question of `Removing empty option in Drop Down Box in Google App Script`? When you use my proposed modification, the empty options were removed?

Comment: Yeah bro you are correct. Using your modification, I was able to remove the empty box bro.

Comment: Of course I can do that bro. You are helping me. Okay let me get to the new question bro.

Comment: @LEE WEI LIANG When the multiple questions are included in one question, it might be confuse other users. But, I think that when you resolve your issues for each question, those your questions will be useful for other users who have the same issue. I think that those will become the property for a lot of users.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67645366/filter-the-tables-in-html-part-of-google-app-script - The link for the new post bro. Thank you so much for your helps bro.

Comment: Sure I will listen to you , my mentor